# How to automatically fix Orphaned Users with PowerShell and SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server-2012, sqlcmd

I'm trying to properly capture output from SQLCMD in SQL Server 2012.

Here is the PS script:

```powershell
$dbname = "MyDB"
$InstanceTarget = "localhost\SQLEXPRESS"

$FixOrphansSQL=@"
WITH login_CTE (name, type, sid)
As
(
Select name, type, sid from sys.database_principals where type = 'S'
)
select 'ALTER USER '+a.name+' WITH LOGIN ='+a.name As Fixusers from sys.server_principals a JOIN login_CTE b ON a.sid <> b.sid and a.name = b.name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS 
GO
"@
$RepairOrphansSQL = sqlcmd -S $InstanceTarget -Q $FixOrphansSQL -d $dbname
sqlcmd -S $InstanceTarget -Q $RepairOrphansSQL -d $dbname
```

If I run this

```
sqlcmd -S $InstanceTarget -Q $FixOrphansSQL -d $dbname
```

it works and the result is the script commands (on separate lines) to fix the orphaned users – but with some extra characters:

```
(lots of dashes -----------------)
ALTER USER InsightETLUser WITH LOGIN =InsightETLUser                                                                                                                                                                                     
ALTER USER APSDT_CDLinkedServerUser WITH LOGIN =APSDT_CDLinkedServerUser                                                                                                                                                                 

(2 rows affected)
```

When I run

```powershell
$RepairOrphansSQL = sqlcmd -S $InstanceTarget -Q $FixOrphansSQL -d $dbname
```

nothing gets captured into `$RepairOrphansSQL`.

Comment: If you are using PowerShell why use `sqlcmd`, just use `Invoke-Sqlcmd` then it will be output as an data table. If you want just the output as strings just pipe it to `select -ExpandProperty Fixusers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "(lots of dashes -----------------)" you talk about are a result of the output from sqlcmd.  Instead of using `SELECT` in your script, you likely want to use `PRINT` with a cursor.  `SELECT` will generate a resultset that sqlcmd will print to the screen along with header info.  The dashes are part of this header info.

The T-SQL won't work for logins/users that have spaces in their names, or other special characters such as dashes, etc.  To make it work correctly for those users/logins, you need to wrap the name in square brackets, using `QUOTENAME()`.

Something like this:

```
$dbname = "test"
$InstanceTarget = "CP708-D377\MV2012"

$FixOrphansSQL=@"
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cmd = '';
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC
FOR
SELECT FixUsersCmd = 'ALTER USER ' + QUOTENAME(dp.name) + ' 
    WITH LOGIN = ' + QUOTENAME(sp.name) + ';'
FROM sys.database_principals dp
    INNER JOIN sys.server_principals sp ON dp.name = sp.name AND dp.sid <> sp.sid
    AND dp.type_desc = 'SQL_USER';
OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @cmd;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
END
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
"@
$RepairOrphansSQL = sqlcmd -S $InstanceTarget -Q $FixOrphansSQL -d $dbname
echo $RepairOrphansSQL
if ($RepairOrphansSQL.Length -gt 0) {
    sqlcmd -S $InstanceTarget -Q $RepairOrphansSQL -d $dbname
}
```

The above code checks if `$RepairOrphansSQL` actually contains any commands before running it; if the variable is empty, sqlcmd is not called.

Comment: Thanks Max!  This did the trick with one tweak - I had to remove the QUOTENAME() in the ALTER USER statement so that sqlcmd could parse the query.

Comment: What modification did you make?  I tested the code above on my local 2012 instance using powershell, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: SQLCMD.EXE : Sqlcmd: 'ALTER USER [ETLUser] WITH LOGIN = [ETLUser];': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.
At line:1 char:7
+ sqlcmd <<<<  -S $InstanceTarget -Q $RepairOrphansSQL -d $dbname
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Sqlcmd: 'ALTER ... '-?' for help.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: So I just changed the SELECT statement to "SELECT FixUsersCmd = 'ALTER USER ' + dp.name + ' WITH LOGIN = ' + sp.name + ';'

Comment: If you have a user name like "some sql server" that code won't work.  What version of sqlcmd.exe are you using?

Comment: SQL 2014 SP1 installed on Server 2012R2 - don't know how to get version from sqlcmd...